# Will restarting the W3SVC Web Publishing Service, also restart the app pool in IIS?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, remote-access, windows-service

Background:

I'm trying to stop and start IIS on a windows 7 build box, in order to run acceptance tests.  But from what I have read, most of the remote web management features have been disabled by Microsoft in a retarted attempt to sell more Windows Server 2008 licenses.  Still for some reason they didn't disable the least user-friendly ways of controlling IIS remotely, but they are all a total pain.

What I can do easily is remotely stop and start the WWW service from a msbuild task.  But I want to be sure that this also restarts the app pool, so that when I copy in new web files the web server there will be serving the most recent version of the website.

Question:

If I restart the `W3SVC` windows service, will that also restart the app pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) handles the application pools in IIS 7; here is the [documentation](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/101/introduction-to-iis-7-architecture/#WWW).

[How To](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732317%28WS.10%29.aspx) start and stop the services.

Comment: Bravo, sir, the answer I was looking for!